Dealing with Underdispersion in Poisson Regression (GLM) with count data as a response variable
Related to glm() in R,  I am working with count data (number of mammal species on islands) and following statistical theory, I have fitted a glm(y ~ x, family=poisson) where x is one or two numeric predictors. However, after fitting the model I get a low dispersion ratio (~0.4) from tests (e.g check_overdispersion()) indicating underdispersion. Similarly, when I run my possible final model (with one predictor) I get:
    Null deviance: 44.039 on 27 degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 11.473 on 26 degrees of freedom

My sample size consists of ~30 different islands and predictors are significant. From simple descriptives I observe that my response variable (species richness) is overdispersed.
I know that underdispersion is quite unusual and I have read the few related posts with somewhat similar examples and possible solutions (e.g., Conway–Maxwell–Poisson regression). Nevertheless, I cannot find a clear answer on how to process my data.
My two main concerns are:

Species richness is a known over-dispersed variable in ecology. My predictors are mainly log10 transformed variables regarding area (km2) and distance/isolation (km).
However, I get underdispersion when I fit the glm (family=poisson) model with my predictors. Is it possible to get underdispersion due to log-transforming my predictors? (I did this in order to achieve linearity between the response variable and certain predictors)

In addition, I want to know if I can fit a quasi-poisson regression for my dataset and solve the problem as in the case of overdispersion. If so, should I be concerned about the factors that caused the underdispersion?


